# How to transfer ETH between two addresses using geth and json rpc

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, json-rpc, light-clients, php

I have [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) running on my server. I am building a php website which act as wallet. Now iam able to create addresses.
I need to be able to deposit and withdraw ETH between addresses on same node.  I start geth with below command.

```
go-ethereum/build/bin/geth console  --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --rpccorsdomain "*" --syncmode "light"
```

How to acheive the functionality of a wallet on geth over rpc ? Is there a command or API call for that? Iam finding it hard to understand the documentation.

**UPDATE**: What I want to do is transfer ETH from one account to another. Below are the api calls i tried and the errors I got in the browser when i call transfer function in my php class. Can someone please correct me

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"personal_signAndSendTransaction","params":[[{"from":"0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155","to":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567","gas":"0x76c0","gasPrice":"0x9184e72a000","value":"0x9184e72a","data":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"}],"passphrase"]}

Fatal error: Uncaught RPCException: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type eth.SendTxArgs

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"personal_sendTransaction","params":[[{"from":"0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155","to":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567","gas":"0x76c0","gasPrice":"0x9184e72a000","value":"0x9184e72a","data":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"}],"passphrase"]}

Fatal error: Uncaught RPCException: The method personal_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available thrown

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155","to":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567","gas":"0x76c0","gasPrice":"0x9184e72a000","value":"0x9184e72a","data":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"}]}

Fatal error: Uncaught RPCException: account is locked thrown

**Please help!**

Comment: do not use eth_sendTransaction, you are going to have to unlock the account and that's insecure. Your users are going to be hacked and you are going to be hated. Ese eth_sendRawTransaction and sign transaction before sending it, with javascript . Your best example is myphpwallet, download the sources and just copy all the process of signing transaction and youre done

Comment: can you please send a link to myphpwallet

Comment: sorry, it is myetherwallet, not myphpwallet

Comment: download chrome extension

Answer (score 2):

In Geth console, you can use the sendTransaction function :

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: "0xE618A4B5A516f371Ce26d9A1DBE7839F4e3812GB",
    to: "0xE618A4B5A516f371Ce26d9A1DBE7839F4e3812CB",
    value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")
})
```

Comment: I want to interact with geth from my browser using json rpc. Is there a method to convert 1 etc to 'web3.toWei(1, "ether")})' format that i can pass ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [eth_sendtransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction) to send a transaction to the destination

In the params section

```
params: [{
    "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
    "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
    "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400
    "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
    "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
    "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```

You should get back a transaction signature

```
{
    "id":1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": "0xe670ec64341771606e55d6b4ca35a1a6b75ee3d5145a99d05921026d1527331"
}
```

This works on accounts that have been unlocked in geth previously

Comment: if i have an address, I want to add 1 ETC to that address, How can I do that?

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: can we send ether to an address outside of my network?

Comment: You need to buy some Ether, send them to the account that is unlocked in the `geth` client and you should be able to send fractions of that Ether to other adresses.

Comment: What does "outside of your network" mean? How do you define your network?

You can send Ether to any address. Even if the address does not exist.

Comment: i meant addresses generated by other exchanges like bitrex  as  "outside of your network" . But I got your point.

Comment: can you please show an example if I have money how should i do the api call

Comment: can deposit and withdraw be done by 
eth_sendTransaction call

Comment: Withdraw doesn't really exist as a concept inside the Ethereum network. It just means sending ETH to another address. So yes, it can be done by `eth_sendTransaction`

Comment: The other answer is a very good example how to send Ether from one address to another

Comment: I want to interact with geth from my browser using json rpc. Is there a method to convert 1 etc to 'web3.toWei(1, "ether")})'  format that i can pass ?

Comment: There's no way to convert ETC to ETH in a blockchain context

Comment: sorry spelling mistake!! i wanted to transfer 1 ETH from one etherum address(genrated by geth node running on my server) to another ethereum address(may be on some exchange) using json rpc. Is that possible? I have updated my questions with the calls i tried